# Comparing two discrete samples using an adapted KS test

Tags: r

I have to compare two discrete samples (one of a small size i.e about 300 observations) using a KS test. However, the kS test is designed for continuous variables as you know. So, I have to adapt the test to deal with discrete variables but I do not know exactly how. There is a ks.test function in package dgof but it only allows one-sample tests and I would like to implement two-sample tests for discrete distributions and calculate exact p-values in R. Do you know someone who has implemented this before? I read somewhere that a permutation test approach can be useful in this case but I do not know how to proceed. Thank you.

Comment: Stats methods question belong on CV.com. You should edit your question to explain why using the wrong test is being required.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your comment. What did you mean "with using the wrong test"?

Comment: You've already said you know that the `ks.test` is designed for continuous variables. What are you failing to understand?

Comment: It is not exactly the answer I waited for. There are people who try to adapt the ks test to discrete distributions and people who use it with discrete variables. I am pretty sure they are not stupid.

Comment: I originally said this belonged on a different forum. SO is for coding questions where the questioner can describe a specific algorithm. I agree that a permutation approach would make sense, but the KS test is not a permutation method. You should post a question on CrossValidated.com that has more details about the specific relationships that you want to examine. Not all "discrete" distributions are ordered for instance, but some are.

Comment: You can implement a ks test using a permutation method. It is useful to determine exact p-values in presence of ties.

Comment: Right but that was not the question, rather the obverse of the question.

Comment: wherever I ask a question, there is always someone who tells me to do It on another site. I feel as if I go round in circles. Never mind. I will try elsewhere. Thanks.